# ГРАФОМОТОРНЫЕ - слитно или через дефис?

Tags: слитно-дефис, орфография

Слитно или через дефис пишется прилагательное "ГРАФОМОТОРНЫЕ"?

Comment: @сумкин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

> Слитно или через дефис?

См. http://orthography.academic.ru/6139 :

> **графо...** (греч. пишу) — первая часть сложных слов, **пишется слитно**
>
> *Слитно. Раздельно. Через дефис.. Б. З. Букчина*

Comment: Никогда не следует говорить "всегда", так как дефисное написание слов тоже встречается, например: Графо-аналитический расчет усилительного каскада ОЭ на биполярном транзисторе.

Comment: И написание слова **чёрт** через **"о"** тоже встречается. И что с того?..

Comment: Здесь дефисное написание не просто встречается,  здесь оно абсолютно грамотно использовано,так так обозначает сочинительную связь основ, даже союз И можно поставить: графическое и аналитическое решение задачи.

Answer (score 2):

1) Моторные навыки - это маленькие, утонченные движения мышцами, которые необходимы для того, чтобы мастерски делать изящные вещи. Графомоторные навыки - это умение свободно выполнять мелкие и точные двигательные движения руками в процессе выполнения графических задач, связанных с графикой (письмом).

2) Встречается как слитное, так и раздельное написание прилагательного "графомоторный", но правильным следует считать слитное написание. Схема образования: моторный - графомоторный, это чистое сложение основ графо + моторный.

3) **Но нельзя сказать, что для "графо" сочинено отдельное правило, по которому все слова с этим элементом пишутся слитно.** Форма написание слов с "графо" должна соответствовать общему правилу написания сложных прилагательных.

К примеру,  слово "графо-аналитический"  можно писать через дефис, так как сложное прилагательное составлено из основ прилагательных с сочинительной связью (можно вставить союз и), с усечением первой основы: графический и аналитический - графо-аналитический, сравнить: английский и русский - англо-русский.

Орфография подобных слов неоднозначна, может встречаться как слитное, так и раздельное написание.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что половина на половину... Вот что [открылось в поиске](http://go.mail.ru/search?q=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&fr=ntg&gp=profitraf3). За себя скажу, что я бы использовал только слитное написание.